# Creating web services with scalable open source technologies

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-authentication

We would like to have some recommendation for creating restful web services. We went through many article and answers. Most of the answers are specific to a framework. Can someone please point us to comparison article which helps me to understand different frameworks? 
Please explain how to handle login and use web services.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way to answer this other than it depends.  If your talking open source, the standard for a long time was Linux, Apache and MySQL for database (and PHP a.k.a. LAMP) , but some folks prefer PostGres, or a No SQL solution like Mongo DB or Couch DB.

Given that, you need to decide if you want to build on top of a framework(s), and choose a language direction.  If you want Java, Spring and Hibernate have pretty good support, and are fairly mature.

Most shops have a set of developers with certain skills that you can leverage, and typically, that's how the decision is made.  You don't want to do something completely new and have to retrain everyone.

Without knowing what your goal is, or anything about your situation, it's going to be tough to suggest a reasonable path forward.  Sometimes you need to look at how your going to host your site, and find vendors that support your stack.  A little research will help you figure out where you need to go.

Sometimes its worth abandoning the open source path, and go with something like IIS and ASP .NET.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Our problem is not much write intensive for now. It might become write intensive going forward. NoSQL as backend will help us in that case and we are good at java. Would spring framework help us? I just need your suggestion.